# How to send Multipart data and json object from ajax to spring

Tags: angularjs, spring, file-upload, annotations, httprequest

I have done a poc to upload(drag&drop) file from angular js by sending multi part request to controller(Sprig), but i need to send some more parameters along with file(Multi part content) can any one suggest me to post file(Multi part content) and json object to controller.

Comment: Can you post your actual code or a sample of it? So we can play with it.

Comment: sorry for your convinience, actually i dont have client source code i am doing in server site part only

Answer (score 0):

You can't do both just in one method. If it's a big object I suggest to create another method and call it after or before file upload. Otherwise for e.g. if you have HTML form you can do something like this:

```
var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('file-upload-form'));
$.ajax({
    url: /file/upload,
    data: form,
    dataType: 'text',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function () {
        //Do something
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Then in your Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
    MultipartFile file;

    try {
        file = request.getFile(itr.next()); //Get the file.
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    }

    String param = request.getParamterer("paramName"); //Get your parameters

    //Do something else.
}
```

You have to declare [MultipartHttpServletRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html) which will contain the file and all form data of your request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yah thaks, it helps me lot